# Calculate a policy locking

Tags: nft, minting, policy

How can I calculate when the policy is going to be locked? I have the policy script file and I need to specify the `before` slot but I don't know how to calculate it.

For example, I want the policy to be locked in 6 months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the slot lenght is one second, this is pretty easy.

1. Find the current slot number.

```
$ curl -s  -H "project_id: $BLOCKFROST_PROJECT_ID" https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/blocks/latest | jq .slot
40664369
```

2. Add 6 months to it (roughly)

```
$ expr 40664369 + $((60*60*24*30*6))
56216369
```